# Can I view more extensive IL in LINQPad?

Tags: c#, .net, linqpad, il

When you view IL code in LINQPad you get something like this:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ret         

Program.Main:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello World"
IL_0006:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000B:  nop         
IL_000C:  ret         

Program..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  ret
```

This is a "cleaned up" view that left out some things like method/class signatures which you can view using other tools (Ildasm, Reflector, etc):

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Program extends [mscorlib] System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldstr      "Hello World"
    IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b:  nop
    IL_000c:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib] System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  ret
  } // end of method Program::.ctor
} // end of class Program
```

Is there a way to view this more extensive IL code in LINQPad?

Comment: what do you mean by more extensive? , that il code looks just about what you get?

Comment: @Thorarins: it does not include the `.method` and `.class` segments..

Comment: aha ok , well short answer is no then :)  . .method and .class is not il , it is stuff the decompiler puts in to make it more readable

Comment: @Thorarins Mainly to make it compilable.